# Why LuaTeX does not open file without extension?

Tags: luatex

LuaTeX-0.80.0

Suppose in current directory we have a simple text file, called `text` (without extension). The following code gives error in LuaTeX, but works fine in TeX. Why? Is there a simple workaround to make this work?

```
\newread\infile
\openin\infile=text
\ifeof\infile
\message{I am not able to open the file for reading}
\fi
\closein\infile
\bye
```

The answer should remark specifically which design decisions in LuaTeX justifies this odd behavior. Is this just a bug which has not been fixed or it is intentional?

Besides, are there any reasons why luatex must append .tex extension in opening file for writing? Why always force an extension if files can quite reasonably be used without it?

Comment: @MikeRenfro: this should be the answer

Comment: One may question in this setting the fact that `TeX` will allow opening a file without extension for reading (as your mwe shows), but not for writing (as you may check; it will always add `.tex` extension if none is present). I don't know however if `LuaTeX`'s design decision is based on re-establishing symmetry.